# Request not found error in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Laravel version 5.3 and i created a file `createArticleRequest.php` under the `request` folder , which looks like below:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateArticleRequest extends Request {


    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return  [
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'body'  => 'required',
            'published_at'  => 'required|date',
        ]
    }


} 

?>
```

In My articles controller i have the following method:

```
public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request) {
        // $input = Request::all();
        Article::create($request->all());
        return redirect('articles');
}
```

But when i fill the form in my view and click on submit i get an error like so:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 286:
Class App\Http\Controllers\CreateArticleRequest does not exist
```

Why am i getting this error ??

I believe my articles Controller and my createArticlesRequest are in the same `namespace` so why am i getthing this error?

Comment: The controller is looking for CreateArticlesRequent in App\Http\Controllers namespace, so fully reference it as "public function store(App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest $request)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use PHP' `use` keyword at the top of the PHP file, so that php can find the CreateArticleRequest package Class in the right namespace like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest;

class Controller {

    public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request) {
            // $input = Request::all();
            Article::create($request->all());
            return redirect('articles');
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!